# grid.raster and jpeg issue on R 3.0.0

Tags: r, jpeg

The following code is giving me a different output on the 2 different `R` versions

**R 2.5.3**

```
#R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

r <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
g <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
b <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)

col <- rgb(r, g, b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)

library(grid)

> jpeg(filename="image.jpg")
> grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
> dev.off()
windows 
      2 

> grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```

[image]

**R 3.0.0**

```
#R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(grid)
> jpeg(filename="image.jpg")
Error in jpeg(filename = "image.jpg") : unable to start jpeg() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In jpeg(filename = "image.jpg") :
  unable to open file 'image.jpg' for writing
2: In jpeg(filename = "image.jpg") : opening device failed
> grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

In `R 3.0.0`, `jpeg` gives the above error but **also** `grid.raster` seems not to work:

```
 > grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```

gives a completely white (or maybe transparent) image. Can you replicate that?

**NB**: If I open R through `RStudio` I'm able to use `jpeg` but `grid.raster` still doesn't work, so I get any way

```
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

and a nothing into `image.jpg`

Comment: Works fine for me under `R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03);
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`. To make you example reproducible you should set a seed also.

Comment: Might be time to reinstall R....

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error evan I have the same R/system configurations. I used `knitr` to test the `grid.raster` output on differents devices. Here my *Mrakdown* file code:

````
```{r}
set.seed(1)
r <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
g <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
b <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
col <- rgb(r, g, b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)
```
```{r,dev='jpeg'}
library(grid)
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```
```{r,dev='png'}
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```
```{r,dev='pdf'}
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```
````